# Error : java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, interface

when am running my action i faced Error : 
" java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String "

and this is my code :

```
 textField_1 = new JTextField();
       textField_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           Object selected = list_1.getSelectedValue();
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            String a =null;
         try{

   conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/flyer","root","000");
   String query= " INSERT INTO flyer_item (discount)  SELECT price * ? FROM `item` WHERE item_name = `?` ";
   Statement st= conn.createStatement();

   java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                        ps.setString(1,a);
                        ps.setString(2,(String) selected);
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                        st.executeUpdate(query);


                    } catch (SQLException se){
                        System.out.println(se.getMessage());

                    } }} );
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Selected is an array-list and you are trying to convert it into string which is not possible:

```
ps.setString(2,(String) selected);
```

What you should do?

```
ps.setString(2, selected.tostring());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: Glad to help you..may i get some likes..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this line ?

```
       Object selected = list_1.getSelectedValue();
```

Make sure **selected** is a String before casting . You can use **instanceof** operator to check the Object type.

Comment: yah you are right , thank you !